# How can I contribute to an existing rails gem/engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, open-source, rails-engines

What is the best way to extent and contribute to a rails `gem/engine`

I have found this blog [gem/engine](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue) , which I want to use it in my rails3 application.

But there are few modifications / features I would like to have and I'm willing do code them. And after that I would like to add them to the original `gem/engine` (if the author permits)

But I'm confused with how and where to code and test my new changes.

So far I have done the followings

1 - Fork the `gem/engine` to my github account

2 - clone the source to my local machine

3 - created a sample rails app and added the `gem` (from my github account)

My question is,

How can I do the code changes to the `gem` and test them. Gem itself has used rspec and I could do that too, but some of the changes I'm planning (like layout changes), is litttle hard to check with rspec.

this `gem` in using `rails > 3`

Comment: just change the code of your cloned repo and once happy submit a pull request upstream. if you add features, you better add tests. what is wrong with rspec?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent ScreenCast about it: [RailsCasts: Contributing to Open Source](http://railscasts.com/episodes/300-contributing-to-open-source)